# React-Native native-base How to decrease the spacing between card Items?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
render() {
  return(
    <Card style={{  padding: 0 }}>
      <CardItem listItemPadding={0} header style=styles.Card}>
        <Text style={styles.cardText}>
          {this.props.library.title}
        </Text>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

The docs say that **`listItemPadding`** can be used but it's not working
I have tried to change the padding of  to 0 but it's not working either.

Comment: Check this out:
[Github issues #1219](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1219)

Answer (score 3):

Use the **cardBody** attribute in **cardItem** it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to use **`listItemPadding`** prop which [doesn't exist at the moment](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/CardItem.js).

`ListItem`, `Card` and `CardItems`, each have some padding or margin of their own. You can just inspect the screen, check it and remove the padding/margin as per your requirement using style. Or you can eject NativeBase theme ([Customize](http://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#Customize)) and do your changes in the theme of those components. That way you will have the same styles for those components in your whole app.

Probably you are looking for a **`paddingVertical`** property. You can add a negative value and then edit your component style as you will normally do.

> native-base-theme/components/CardItem.js

```
paddingVertical: variables.cardItemPadding - 5,
```

Then on your component:

```
render() {
  return(
    <Card style={{  padding: 10 }}>
      <CardItem header style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
        <Text>Item</Text>
      </CardItem>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
render() {
        return(

<View style={{  flex: 0,
 elevation: 3,
 shadowColor: "#000",
 shadowOpacity: 0.1,
 shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
 shadowRadius: 1.0,
 marginVertical: 1,
 borderRadius: 2,
 marginHorizontal: 1,
 margin: 0,
 padding: 0,
borderWidth: 0, }}>

                 <CardItem listItemPadding={0} header style=styles.Card}>
                     <Text style={styles.cardText}>
                         {this.props.library.title}
                     </Text>
                 </CardItem>

             </View>

        );
    }
```

Comment: listItemPadding is not a prop of the CardItem component

Answer (score 0):

> **you can use marginTop**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
        shadowRadius: 6,
        shadowOpacity: 0.26,
        elevation: 8,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
        paddingTop: 20,
        width: 400,
        maxWidth: '50%',
        marginTop: 10,
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To control the padding,  put all the sides...

paddingLeft: 0,
paddingRight: 0,
paddingTop: 0,
paddingBottom: 0

...you can then put the appropriate padding number in any of the sides. But declare padding for all the four sides.

Comment: This was helpful. In my case I wanted to remove padding around the text and adding "padding: 0" wasn't helpful but this worked.