# Card component with image doesnt completely fit on card

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

Bottom space in card component with image prop.

I am trying to show some cards with images but couldnt remove the white space in bottom of card. I want to image to fit the container (Card).
I have also tried to use sepearte Image component within Card component but no luck. I tried to debug using react devTools but it always crashes when I expand Card element in dev tools saying 'invalid height and width on Text'.

I have used this code to render cards with images:

```
            <FlatList data ={
              [
                {key : '1', title : 'Hello1', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '2', title : 'Hello2', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '3', title : 'Hello3', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '4', title : 'Hello4', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '5', title : 'Hello5', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '6', title : 'Hello6', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), },
                {key : '7', title : 'Hello7', image : require('./images/kebabs.jpg'), }

              ]
            }

            renderItem={
              ({item})  =>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.handleNavigate()}}>
                    <Card
                        containerStyle={{paddingTop: 1}}                        
                        featuredTitle = {item.title}
                        image ={item.image}
                        imageProps={{resizeMode: 'cover'}}
                        imageStyle={{width : '100%', minWidth : '100%', height : 60}}                        
                        >
                    </Card>                        
                </TouchableOpacity>
              }
              ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
              />
        </ImageBackground>
```

The component is rendered as below (white space below the image)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ListItem`, `Card` and `CardItems`, each have some padding or margin of their own. You can just inspect the screen, check it and remove the padding/margin as per your requirement using style. Or you can eject NativeBase theme (Customize) and do your changes in the theme of those components. That way you will have the same styles for those components in your whole app.

Probably you are looking for a `paddingVertical` property. You can add a negative value and then edit your component style as you will normally do.

> native-base-theme/components/CardItem.js

```
paddingVertical: variables.cardItemPadding - 5,
```

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189850/11212074)

OR

Use View, Imagebackground, and Text instead of Card.

example.js:

```
<View>
<Imagebackground>
<Text> </Text>
</Imagebackground>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try ImageBackground before using Cards but wanted a feel of Card in the app. I have also tried inspecting the card component, but I couldnt expand card element, I get a NaN exception on Card component in react dev tools. I cannot see cardItem component in react-native-elements, is it missing in documentation ?

Comment: Is `CardItem` `react-native-element` not `native-base`?

Comment: The Card component I have used is from react-native-element. I am just using Imagebackground and Text within FlatList to achieve card look and feel now.